# SqlAlchemy: query array of objects in JSONB field

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to know how to do exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486192/postgresql-query-array-of-objects-in-jsonb-field), except in SQLAlchemy instead of pure SQL syntax.

So just to reiterate from that question, you have a table with column of type jsonb, let's call it `data`.  In this scenario `data` will always be an array of objects.  I would like to query for rows where `data` contains an object with a key set to a specific value.

The answer I've linked here gives a great explanation for how to do it in SQL language, how do I do the same thing in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the jsonb key remains a jsonb object. This is simply solved by using the [`astext`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_11.html#change-3503-cast) syntax.

So if your `jsonb` column is called `data` in the `MyObject` table:

```
object = session.query(
    MyObject
).\
    filter(MyObject.data['key'].astext=='required_key').\
    all()
```