# Querying Postgres 9.6 JSONB array of objects

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE trip
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    gps_data_json jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

The JSON in gps_data_json contains an array of of trip objects with the following fields (sample data below):

- mode
- timestamp
- latitude
- longitude

I'm trying to get all rows that contain a certain "mode".

```
SELECT * FROM trip
where gps_data_json ->> 'mode' = 'WALK';
```

I pretty sure I'm using the ->> operator wrong, but I'm unsure who to tell the query that the JSONB field is an array of objects?

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO trip (gps_data_json) VALUES
  ('[
      {
        "latitude": 47.063480377197266,
        "timestamp": 1503056880725,
        "mode": "TRAIN",
        "longitude": 15.450349807739258
      },
      {
        "latitude": 47.06362533569336,
        "timestamp": 1503056882725,
        "mode": "WALK",
        "longitude": 15.450264930725098
      }
    ]');

INSERT INTO trip (gps_data_json) VALUES
  ('[
      {
        "latitude": 47.063480377197266,
        "timestamp": 1503056880725,
        "mode": "BUS",
        "longitude": 15.450349807739258
      },
      {
        "latitude": 47.06362533569336,
        "timestamp": 1503056882725,
        "mode": "WALK",
        "longitude": 15.450264930725098
      }
    ]');
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem arises because `->>` operator cannot walk through array:

- First unnest your json array using `json_array_elements` function;
- Then use the operator for filtering.

Following query does the trick:

```
WITH 
A AS (
SELECT
    Id
   ,jsonb_array_elements(gps_data_json) AS point
FROM trip
)
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE (point->>'mode') = 'WALK';
```

Comment: You can use [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and avoid cast.

Answer (score 16):

Unnesting the array works fine, if you only want the objects containing the values queried.
The following checks for containment and returns the full JSONB:

```
SELECT * FROM trip
WHERE gps_data_json @> '[{"mode": "WALK"}]';
```

See also [Postgresql query array of objects in JSONB field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486192/postgresql-query-array-of-objects-in-jsonb-field)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  from
    (select id, jsonb_array_elements(gps_data_json) point from trip where id = 16) t
where point @> '{"mode": "WALK"}';
```

In My Table, `id = 16` is to make sure that the specific row is jsonb-array datatype ONLY. Since other rows data is just JSONB object. So you must filter out jsonb-array data FIRST. Otherwise : `ERROR:  cannot extract elements from an object`