# Query JSONB array of object's for subfield

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, ruby-on-rails-6

I am running into a roadblock and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46789897/querying-postgres-9-6-jsonb-array-of-objects)'s second answer gets me so close!

Using postgresql I have a jsonb, places, on my orders table with the following shape:

```rb
[
 { "delivery_place" : { "id" : "abc", "name" : "my place" } },
 { "delivery_place" : { "id" : "xyz", "name" : "your place" } }
]
```

My goal is to use an ILIKE to query the "name" details to retrieve the correct orders. Normally I would do that with:

`select id from orders, jsonb_array_elements(orders.places) as places where places -> 'delivery_place' ->> 'name' ILIKE '%my%'`

I am using Rails 6 and already have a `.from()` clause defined and can not easily overwrite it for an optional search criteria. So I am trying to figure out how to do this with just the `where` clause.

The linked post above seems to get me 90% of the way there by using the `@>` operator. Thus I could do `select id from orders where orders.places @> '["delivery_place" : {"name": "my place"}]'` However I can't figure out how to combine this with an ILIKE.

Is this even possible? If not, is there a way that I am just not noticing? Trying ot use the jsonb_array_elements in the where directly gave me an error but perhaps there is a way? If not does anyone know any resources for learning how to use `with` clauses in Rails 6?

Comment: Unrelated to your Rails problem, but the plain SQL query would be more efficient using `from orders where exists (select * from jsonb_array_elements(...) where ... ILIKE ...)`

Comment: I think you just saved me so much headache. I quick try of doing a where exists (select...) worked well for me. I will have to implement in full and test but this may have just answered my question! 

Thank you so kindly!

Comment: Yep, that worked like a charm!

Thanks again! Feel free to make it a real answer reply and I can +1 it!