# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jsonb

I need a help for the below mentioned detail,

I am using Postgres + Spring-Data-JPA. Moreover, I have used the `jsonb` data type for storing data.

I am trying to execute a query, but it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

The cause here is that I have added a `jsonb` condition in the `WHERE` clause (kindly refer to the below query for more detail).

**Query** (I have renamed column name just because of hiding the actual column name):

```
select distinct
    jsonb_array_elements(initiated_referral_detail->'listOfAttribue')::jsonb
        ->>  'firstName' as firstName,
    jsonb_array_elements(initiated_referral_detail->'listOfAttribue')::jsonb
        ->>  'lastName' as lastName,
    jsonb_array_elements(initiated_referral_detail->'listOfAttribue')::jsonb
        ->>   'country' as country  
from
    tale1 table10_ 
left outer join
    table2 table21_ 
        on table10_.end_user_id=table21_.end_user_id 
left outer join
    table3 table32_ 
        on table10_.manufacturer_id=table32_.manufacturer_id  
where
    table21_.end_user_uuid=(
        ?
    ) 
    and table21_.is_active=true 
    and table32_.manufacturer_uuid=(
        ?
    ) 
    and table32_.is_active=true 
    and table10_.is_active=true 
    and table32_.is_active=true 
    and jsonb_array_elements(initiated_referral_detail->'listOfAttribue')::jsonb
        ->>  'action' = ('PENDING') 
order by
    jsonb_array_elements(initiated_referral_detail->'listOfAttribue')::jsonb
        ->>  'firstName',
    jsonb_array_elements(initiated_referral_detail->'listOfAttribue')::jsonb
        ->>  'lastName'
limit ?
```

The following line in the above query is causing the error:

```
and jsonb_array_elements(initiated_referral_detail->'listOfAttribue')::jsonb
    ->> 'action' = ('PENDING')
```

Can anyone please guide me about how do fetch data from the inner JSON? Especially in my case I have an inner List and a few elements inside.

Comment: The error message seems to be rather clear. What is the actual question?

Comment: @JensSchauder I am not clear about this error. may be am novice for this. #2. I would like to know more about how can I add where clause condition which is used for nested JSON element. if you have any link/article then please share with me/us for the further clarification.

Comment: Not an expert here, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486192/postgresql-query-array-of-objects-in-jsonb-field

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a lateral join with `jsonb_array_elements` for cases like that. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE tale1 (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   initiated_referral_detail jsonb NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tale1 VALUES
   (1, '{
          "name": "one",
          "listOfAttribue": [
                              { "id": 1, "action": "DONE"},
                              { "id": 2, "action": "PENDING" },
                              { "id": 3, "action": "ACTIVE" }
                            ]
        }');

INSERT INTO tale1 VALUES
   (2, '{
          "name": "two",
          "listOfAttribue": [
                              { "id": 1, "action": "DONE"},
                              { "id": 2, "action": "ACTIVE" }
                            ]
        }');
```

To find all `id`s where the associated JSON contains an array element with `action` = `PENDING`, you can query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM tale1 CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     jsonb_array_elements(initiated_referral_detail -> 'listOfAttribue') AS attr
WHERE attr ->> 'action' = 'PENDING';
```