# Update JSONB column where JSONB column has certain value postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table named `guest_group` in a Postgres DB and a column named `custom_fields` with the following values: (example)

```
[
   {
      "value":"Frau Barbara Test",
      "display_name":"Name",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "full-name"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"118",
      "display_name":"Zimmernummer",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "room-number"
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"likes postgreSQL",
      "display_name":"Traces",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "trace"
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to update all rows with the

- `value` equals to `Frau Barbara Test` and where the `servicio_tags` array is equals to `["full-name"]`
- plus where the `value` equal to `118` where the `servicio_tags` array is equal to `["room-number"]`

The Update should add a new object to the JSONB:

```
{
   "value":"likes JSONB",
   "display_name":"Traces",
   "servicio_tags":[
      "trace"
   ]
}
```

My try so far:

```
UPDATE guest_group 
SET custom_fields = 
jsonb_insert('[{"value": "Frau Barbara Test", "display_name": "Name", "servicio_tags": ["full-name"]}, {"value": "118", "display_name": "Zimmernummer", "servicio_tags": ["room-number"]}]'::jsonb,
'{0}', 
'{"value": "likes JSONB", "display_name": "Traces", "servicio_tags": ["trace"]}'::jsonb, 
true)
 where custom_fields::text like '%"Frau Barbara Test"%'
 and custom_fields::text like '%"118 "%'
```

This try changes the value in column of the specific row to the following:

```
[  
   {  
      "value":"Frau Barbara Test",
      "display_name":"Name",
      "servicio_tags":[  
         "full-name"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "value":"likes JSONB",
      "display_name":"Traces",
      "servicio_tags":[  
         "trace"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "value":"118",
      "display_name":"Zimmernummer",
      "servicio_tags":[  
         "room-number"
      ]
   }
]
```

So the:

```
   {
      "value":"likes postgreSQL",
      "display_name":"Traces",
      "servicio_tags":[
         "trace"
      ]
   }
```

gets lost. How can do the update without loosing this data?

Comment: Do you need the `servicio_tags` array to **equal** that exact value, or do you just need it to contain that respective string (possibly amongst others)?

Comment: The `servicio_tags` array has to be equal to that exact value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not to compare JSON as strings. Instead, use the [vast array of JSON operators and functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html). To find rows that contain Mrs. Test in a value, you could for example use the `@>` operator:

```
WHERE '[{"value": "Frau Barbara Test"}]'::jsonb <@ custom_fields
```

See also [Postgresql query array of objects in JSONB field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28486192/1048572).

However, this doesn't yet check that it's the same object that has a `full-name` tag, so we might try

```
WHERE '[{"value": "Frau Barbara Test", "servicio_tags": ["full-name"]}]'::jsonb <@ custom_fields
```

That's much better than text comparison, but still not exactly what you asked for. Due to the semantics of the `@>` operator, it checks the tags array to *contain* a `"full-name"` string, not to have it as its single element.

To do that, it gets a bit more complicated, involving a subquery on the `jsonb_array_elements` and accessing its json components explicitly for comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM guest_group
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS el
  WHERE el->>'value' = 'Frau Barbara Test'
    AND el->'servicio_tags' = '["full-name"]'::jsonb)
```

You could also mix the two approaches using `ANY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM guest_group
WHERE '{"value": "Frau Barbara Test"}' <@ ANY(
  SELECT el
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(custom_fields) AS el
  WHERE el->'servicio_tags' = '["full-name"]'::jsonb)
```

([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8d86d28d714aa08dfb3776c60491aa4a))

Now equipped with these tools, you can add a second condition to match the room number. Then use

```
UPDATE guest_group 
SET custom_fields = jsonb_insert(custom_fields, '{0}', '{"value": "likes JSONB", "display_name": "Traces", "servicio_tags": ["trace"]}'::jsonb, true)
WHERE …
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
UPDATE guest_group 
SET custom_fields = 
jsonb_insert(custom_fields::jsonb,'{0}','{"value": "likes JSONB", "display_name": "Traces", "servicio_tags": ["trace"]}'::jsonb) 
WHERE custom_fields::text like '%"Frau Barbara Test"%'
AND custom_fields::text like '%"117"%'
```